# us-central1 firestore functions are no longer triggering

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I modified the firebase-tools (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) so that I could deploy functions to other regions than us-central1.

Since other regions than us-central1 are supported by the google cloud platform I thought this would work fine.

Deploying europe-west1 worked.

I now had each function showing up two times (once for us-central1 and once for europe-west1) in the google cloud console.

I wondered which of the two functions would be triggered by a firestore write.
It turned out that the europe-west1 function was triggered every time.

Out of curiosity I deleted the europe-west1 function to see what happens. After that the us-central1 function was not being triggered anymore.

Why was the EU function preferred for execution?

Why is the US function no longer working?

Comment: Choosing deployment region is not currently supported for Firebase triggers using the Firebase CLI.  Please wait for an official announcement when this becomes available.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for the answer i will wait for that announcement. But my problem now is that for the project that i tried this on i can no longer get functions(deployed normally to us-central1) to be triggered. For some reason only the eu functions are accepted. Even after deleting all functions and redeploying them the functions don't get triggered.

Comment: Please contact Firebase support.  https://firebase.google.com/support/